# Get repeat value of a field on the base of other field value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table `C_OrderLine` and there are three following fields with stored values;

```
c_orderline_id = 1000
m_product_id = 2000
qty = 5
```

Now I want sql query to get `m_product_id` (2000) in as many line as the value of `qty` (5). Result of query should be as follow:

```
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
```

Comment: Can you give more detail about your query, and some data sample?

Comment: Dear Houari. Answer provided by Radek solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
select inner_query.m_product_id from
(
  select 
    m_product_id,
    generate_series(1, qty)
  from C_OrderLine
) as inner_query
```

Comment: Dear Radek. Your answer helped me and I get what exacttly I want. thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

you mean:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/449)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
with conf(base, cnt) as  (
    values (20000,5)
) 
select conf.base
from conf
join generate_series(1,cnt) on true
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/449/0)**:

```
|  base |
|-------|
| 20000 |
| 20000 |
| 20000 |
| 20000 |
| 20000 |
```

?